# Can NLogC.dll be used with .NET Frameworks prior to 4.0?

Tags: .net, nlog

I am trying to integrate NLog into our application which is C# based using several C++ libraries. So I am trying to use the NLogC DLL to log from the C++ libraries. When I run my application the first attempt to call a NLog_LogVA from my C++ code results in an exception that says the NLogC.dll was built with a newer version of the framework and cannot be loaded.

I am using VS2008 on Win 7 and have .NET 3.5 as my latest installed. However we have been trying to keep our application to only requiring .NET 2.0 since we OEM to multiple customers.

Is it possible to use NLogC with .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the source and recompile it.

[NLog2.source.zip](http://nlog.codeplex.com/releases/32639/download/259972/)

You could also download one of these:

[NLog2.netfx20.zip](http://nlog.codeplex.com/releases/32639/download/259966/)
[NLog2.netfx35.zip](http://nlog.codeplex.com/releases/32639/download/259967/)

Of course I would also assume that the msi download would install 2.0/3.5/4.0 versions of NLog and considering NLogC is just a wrapper I assume your doing something wrong.

The source has a seperate NLOGC solution just download and compile against the framework you want to support.

Comment: Compiling from source worked. The 2/3.5/4 versions were installed by the .msi - but only the 4.0 folder contained an NLogC.dll. The 2/3.5 zips you linked above also do not contain an NLogC.dll. Not sure what I could have been doing wrong there.

Comment: @SteveFallows - I do not use NLOG, so i have no idea whats contained in the msi, but the lack of research before asking for help concerned me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [2.0 release notes](http://nlog-project.org/nlog-2-0-release-notes), this isn't supported.

> NLogC component is supported on .NET Framework 4.0 only.

Glad to know that recompiling works, though.  I guess it's not surprising given that it's likely to be a pretty thin wrapper around the rest of the framework.